# [native-image][build-time] Error: substitution target for io.quarkus.runtime.graal.QuarkusReplacement$GenMain

Tags: java, quarkus, graalvm-native-image

I get the below error when I try to build a native image from an uberjar

Ran the below command:

```sh
./mvnw verify \
           -Pnative -Dquarkus.test.native-image-wait-time=300 \
           -Djavacpp.platform=${OSNAME}-x86_64
```

to build a native image from a uberjar.

Expected a final native image, instead got this error message:

```java
Error: substitution target for io.quarkus.runtime.graal.QuarkusReplacement$GenMain is not loaded. Use field `onlyWith` in the `TargetClass` annotation to make substitution only active when needed.
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: substitution target for io.quarkus.runtime.graal.QuarkusReplacement$GenMain is not loaded. Use field `onlyWith` in the `TargetClass` annotation to make substitution only active when needed.
at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:65)
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.findTargetClass(AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.java:823)
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.handleClass(AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.java:252)
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.init(AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.java:230)
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.createDeclarativeSubstitutionProcessor(NativeImageGenerator.java:875)
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeImage(NativeImageGenerator.java:824)
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:524)
at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$run$0(NativeImageGenerator.java:444)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
```

Bit unsure if I missed out on adding any necessary Quarkus extensions.

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?

Comment: Just running the build again, will let you know asap.

Comment: Okay I'll say it's gone away, I get these messages now, which is far more pleasing to the eyes:

```java
<snipped>
[MLPMnist-1.0.0-runner:92101]    classlist: 112,556.98 ms
[MLPMnist-1.0.0-runner:92101]        (cap):   7,899.96 ms
[MLPMnist-1.0.0-runner:92101]        setup:  14,896.51 ms
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
<snipped>
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
<snipped>
```

Comment: I think we can mark this as resolved.

Comment: Good to hear :)